# MongoDB JAVA : Is there any possible exception when querying?

Tags: java, mongodb, exception, document

As I don’t seem to find in the doc, is there any possibility to get any errors when querying in MongoDB. If yes how can I handle them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a possibility to get errors when interacting with MongoDB. I suggest reading this https://www.javahotchocolate.com/notes/mongodb-errors.html. It provides descriptions for various exceptions that might occur and how to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For example, if you are not connected to a network and you try to access a remote DB, you will get an exception.

How to handle the exception depends on the type of exception that is encountered, as well as how you intend to respond to the exception.